# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{-1} \sqrt \frac{x}{a-x} dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How can we evaluate $$\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{-1} \sqrt \frac{x}{a-x} dx$$

I tried substitutions like $x=a\cos(t)$ and also tried applying property $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x) dx$$ which gave $$\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{-1} \sqrt \frac{a-x}{x}dx$$ but still not able to solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: The integral doesn't seem to make sense: As $x \to a$, the argument of the inverse sine blows up.

Comment: Use a limit of a/2

Comment: The definition domain of $\arcsin$ imposes that $x/(a-x)$ should lie betwin $-1$ and $+1$ ; it means in particular that $x<a/2$.

Comment: If the bounds are changed so that the integral goes from $0$ to $\frac{a}{2}$, the integral evaluates to $\frac{\pi a}{4}(\sqrt{2}-1)$.

Answer (score 4):

**HInts & useful stuff (maybe)**

Very interesting integral.

Mathematica has no result for the DEFINITE integral.

However, a close form for the INDEFINITE integral does exists and it is:

$$
\int\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a}} \right)\ \text{d}x =  G(x, a) = x\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a}}\right)+ +\frac{a\sqrt{\frac{x(a-2x)}{(a-x)^2}}(x-a)\left(2\arctan\left[\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-2x}}\right] - \sqrt{2}\arctan\left[\sqrt{\frac{2x}{a-2x}}\right]\right)}{2\sqrt{x\cdot (a-2x)}}
$$

The problem now is to see how this dos behave in $x = 0$ and $x = a$. For what I can see we have:

$$G(0, a) = 0$$
$$G(a, a) = ??$$

One should try to evaluate that limit, if possible.

Anyway, interesting question. I'll mind more about it.

Comment: Your answer has a slightly different integrand (the root's denominator is reversed), and though _it_ admits a convenient complex form, $$-i\ln\Big(i\sqrt{\tfrac x{x-a}}+\sqrt{1-\tfrac{x}{x-a}}\Big)=-i\ln\Big(i\sqrt{\tfrac x{x-a}}+i\sqrt{\tfrac{a}{x-a}}\Big)=-i\ln i+\ln\tfrac{\sqrt x+\sqrt a}{\sqrt{x-a}}$$ the original one doesn't (namely, $-i\ln\Big(i\sqrt{\tfrac x{a-x}}+\sqrt{\tfrac{a-2x}{a-x}}\Big)$).

I think the OP's problem requires using elliptic integrals.